# Ember-cli , how do i change rest call on fly in the rest adapter

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Im working on ember-cli, how do i change rest call on fly in the rest adapter. If i use path params not query params?for example:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({   
  namespace:'res/v1/users/id',   
  pathForType: function() {  
       return Ember.String.underscore("friends");},});
```

Based on the user selection from dropdown we get the "id", using the id I need to get user friends from the database.
Could you please suggest a better way to do. My aapplication supports pathparams not the query params

Comment: What path you want to call to fetch friends from server? `res/v1/users/id/friends` ?

Comment: yes, id is variable here. It depends on the user i select

Comment: As far as I know there is no **straight** Ember way to do it. There is long discussion about `nested resources api support`: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/186, https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/4. If you manage the backend, you might find that the best option is to change api to avoid using nested resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a variable in enviroment.js 'userId'. When ever i select a user
i set config.userId in the controller to the corresponding Id.

```
config.userId=this.get('selectedUser');
```

In pathforType of adapter I used this varible

```
 pathForType: function() {
    return Ember.String.underscore(config.userId+"/friends");
}
```

you just need to add an import statement

```
import config from '../config/environment';
```

Please suggest me if anyone get to know better way. Thanks all for your responses

Answer (score 1):

To customize the URL, override the [`buildURL` method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL) in your adapter.

The tricky part is to access related records from the adapter. For example, you request friends for a given user. You work in a `friend` adapter, but you need to know the `user`'s id to include it in the URL.

For that purpose, use the [`record` property](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Snapshot.html#property_record) on the `snapshot` argument of the `buildURL` method.

Alternatively, you might want to override some of `buildURL`'s underlying methods such as [`urlForFindQuery`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_urlForFindQuery), depending on how you request your model from the store. With a `find.query()`, you will retrieve the id of the user from the query.

If this does not help you, please respond with the way you're trying to fetch friends from the store.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will see if this helps  me

Answer (score 0):

`buildURL()` only takes the `type` imo. so you have to pass some more jazz.

i did something along the lines of the following in the application adapter

$ ember generate adapter application

app/adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

    findQuery: function(store, type, query) {

        var urlQuery = query.theshityouwant;

        var reply = this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey + '/' + urlQuery), 'GET', { headers: all});
        return reply;
    },
})
```

});